# min(x, y) == NA For-loop with NA Values

Tags: r, for-loop, min, na

I want to choose the minumum value and return it as "The lowest value is: XX".
But I have trouble doing this when i have NA values.

```
x <- c(21,32,123,NA,4,45,65,23)
y <- c(234,2,12,54,87,12,4,123)
myDF<- as.data.frame(cbind(x, y))

for(i in 1:length(myDF$x)) {
  if (min(myDF$x[i], myDF$y[i], na.rm = TRUE) == myDF$x[i]) { cat("The lowest number is: ", myDF$x[i], "\n")}
  else if (min(myDF$x[i], myDF$y[i], na.rm=TRUE) == myDF$y[i]) { cat("The lowest number is: ", myDF$y[i], "\n")}
}
```

It works fine until i get the NA value. My problem is when I get to i=4 I get:

```
min(NA, 54) == NA
```

I want this to return "The lowest number is: 54". But instead my loop break and give me this message.

```
The lowest number is:  21 
The lowest number is:  2 
The lowest number is:  12 
Error in if (min(myDF$x[i], myDF$y[i], na.rm = TRUE) == myDF$x[i]) { : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Whats seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Maybe `apply(myDF, 1, function(x) cat("The lowest number is: ", min(x, na.rm = TRUE), "\n"))`? Though you can vectorize this whole minimum finding process by doing `do.call(pmin, c(myDF, na.rm = TRUE))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the if expression where the right or the left part can get `NA`. You cannot compare anything to `NA`, so for example `if(NA == 6) {...}` would give you exactly the error you described. So make sure that `myDF$x[i]` and `myDF$y[i]` are not `NA` before you compare them using `!is.na(value)` if you have to use it.

In your example though, you actually don't need the if-expression in your command, because of `rm.na = T`. I rebuild your code like this:

```
x <- c(21,32,123,NA,4,45,65,23)
y <- c(234,2,12,54,87,12,4,123)
myDF<- as.data.frame(cbind(x, y))

for(i in 1:length(myDF$x)) {
  cat("The lowest value is: ", min(myDF$x[i], myDF$y[i], na.rm = T), "\n")
}
```

And it returns

```
The lowest value is:  21 
The lowest value is:  2 
The lowest value is:  12 
The lowest value is:  54 
The lowest value is:  4 
The lowest value is:  12 
The lowest value is:  4 
The lowest value is:  23
```

Which should be your expected output.